# Anime with a ship in a sky and people with abilities/powers fighting

Tags: story-identification, anime

There was this anime with like a ship in the sky, all I remember from it is a group of people like a class chasing after this one guy or all running fighting eachother with different abilities (maybe not exactly powers). I remember there being a woman singing a childhood song to a little girl next to a grave or to a robot girl on a bench, it had a second season supposedly and used to be on hulu.

It’s very hard to describe as I remember very little but I believe there was a school on that ship like just a mini thing where some of the group members of the main cast would be in a class and I remember a point where they had something break out of a container so a couple could see it and or fight it.  Right now all I got to go on is it was like a white haired central character. I think the cover of the anime had the group in it or a far away ship. I cant tell if it was an aircraft or an actual ship.

They were all jumping over like one story buildings in their little tag kinda game thing, and it was a more modern drawing style. I think the main character reminds me of the guy from KK anime.

Answer (score 3):

> [Kyoukai Senjou no Horizon](https://myanimelist.net/anime/10456/Kyoukaisenjou_no_Horizon)
>
> In the far future, humans abandon a devastated Earth and travel to
>   outer space. However, due to an unknown phenomenon that prevents them
>   from traveling into space, humanity returns to Earth only to find it
>   inhospitable except for Japan. To accommodate the entire human
>   population, pocket dimensions are created around Japan to house the
>   returned populace. In order to find a way to return to outer space,
>   the humans begin reenacting human history according to the Holy Book
>   Testament. But in the year 1413 of the Testament Era, the nations of
>   the pocket dimensions invade and conquer Japan, dividing the territory
>   into feudal fiefdoms and forcing the original inhabitants of Japan to
>   leave. It is now the year 1648 of the Testament Era, and the refugees
>   of Japan now live in the city ship, Musashi, which constantly travels
>   around Japan while being watched by the Testament Union, the authority
>   that runs the re-enactment of history. However, rumors of an
>   apocalypse and war begin to spread when the Testament stops revealing
>   what happened after 1648. Taking advantage of this situation, Tori
>   Aoi, head of Musashi Ariadust Academy's Supreme Federation and
>   President of the student council, uses this opportunity to lead his
>   classmates and try to regain their homeland.

Why this matches:

1. Musashi is an airship with a school, Mariadust Academy, on it.
2. The main cast are primarily students of the school
3. The chasing scene is actually a racing scene and happens in the first episode.
4. Special powers are present as Divine Weapons.
5. The main cast has white and silver-haired characters.
6. There is a second season which is about the Bloody Mary part of history.

Image of the 2 main characters and the flying ship Musashi:

[image]

The main cover of the first season:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `Norn9` (from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norn9#Anime ):

> It is 1919. A teenage girl arrives on the sailing ship Norn9, where teenagers with special abilities gather.